# How do I make an angled tab interface with just jquery and css3?

Tags: jquery, tabs, css

This is my goal. Angled tabs with transparency on top of the other. How would i build this without using jpgs or pngs, but only css?

[image]

Comment: Would rounded corners do? or do they need to be angled

Comment: this is difficult nigh impossible to do with only CSS. there are some crazy things you can do with javascript of course, but it's definitely not worth the time savings you'd get from just using images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tuts will get you going but I'll try to mockup something in a minute!

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/fun-with-css-shapes/

BTW great question!

Edit:

Here is the "final" result:

[image]

See it [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/2Uf3H/)!

NOTE:

Just be aware that this is a "hack" and that it might not be the best idea to actually implement it, I think (can't try it now) IE has some issues with this, if you asked about usability and accessibility, I would say go with images :)

Comment: This is cool, but what if i wish to add a solid stroke around the tabs like my image? Would be kind of hard if the angled tabs are already borders, no?

Comment: @WillingLearner Let me see.. could be!!

Comment: @WillingLearner nI can't think of anything with css right now because you can't put them one over another and youre allready using the border  http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/2Uf3H/4/ but you could use an image I guess but I know that wasn't your question!

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be with CSS, or are you just hoping not to use raster images? You could for example use an SVG background image, which will likely be a smaller file size than a raster image and will scale better. You can use a data uri if you are worried about HTTP requests. You could also probably use an SVG or png as a border-image if you don't want to use background-image.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this would be to use CSS to create angles:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes
or
http://www.dinnermint.org/blog/css/creating-triangles-in-css/

You create the 'end' piece of the tab as an angle that is white / black, and then use jquery to apply transparency, and selection.

That should help you start without images.